# Sending File from Server to Client by using Netty.io

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to send a file, a client requested from the server, from the server to the client.
The Client specefies the file in the `FileRequestProtocol`, sends it to the server, the server adds the file size to file `FileRequestProtocol` and returns it to the client.

The client adds a new `FileChunkReqWriteHandler` with the correct file size to its pipeline.

The server creates a new `ChunkedFileServerHandler` with the context and the desired file and tries to send it, but the `FileChunkReqWriteHandler` never reads byte from the channel.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Log**

```
INFO  ProtocolHeadHandler:48 - Client send ProtocolHead [version=1, jobType=FILEREQUEST]
INFO  ProtocolHeadServerHandler:36 - Server receive ProtocolHead [version=1, jobType=FILEREQUEST]
INFO  ProtocolHeadHandler:57 - Client ProtocolHead equals, Send Protocol FileRequestProtocol [filePath=test.jpg, fileSize=0]
INFO  FileRequestServerHandler:42 - Server new FileRequest FileRequestProtocol [filePath=test.jpg, fileSize=0]
INFO  FileRequestHandler:41 - Client receives FileRequestProtocol [filePath=test.jpg, fileSize=174878]
INFO  ChunkedFileServerHandler:39 - New ChunkedFileServerHandler
INFO  FileChunkReqWriteHandler:20 - New ChunkedFile Handler FileRequestProtocol [filePath=test.jpg, fileSize=174878]
```

**Client**

FileRequestHandler.java

```
public class FileRequestHandler extends
    SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FileRequestProtocol> {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

public FileRequestHandler() {
}

@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FileRequestProtocol msg) {
    logger.info("Client receives " + msg);
    ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
    ctx.channel().pipeline().addLast(new FileChunkReqWriteHandler(msg));
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    logger.info("Client read complete");
    ctx.flush();
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

FileChunkReqWriteHandler.java

```
public class FileChunkReqWriteHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ChunkedFile> {

FileRequestProtocol fileRequestProtocol;
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());


public FileChunkReqWriteHandler(FileRequestProtocol msg) {
    this.fileRequestProtocol = msg;
    logger.info("New ChunkedFile Handler " + msg);
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    logger.info("in channel active method");
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();

    if (ctx.channel().isActive()) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush("ERR: " +
                cause.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " +
                cause.getMessage() + '\n').addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChunkedFile msg)
        throws Exception {
    logger.info("in channelRead0");

}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    logger.info("channelRead");
    ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
    buf.readBytes(bytes);
    if(buf.readableBytes() >= this.fileRequestProtocol.getFileSize())
    {
        logger.info("received all data");
    }
}
}
```

**Server**

FileRequestServerHandler.java

```
public class FileRequestServerHandler extends
    SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FileRequestProtocol> {

private File f;
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FileRequestProtocol fileRequest) {
    logger.info("Server new FileRequest " + fileRequest);
    f = new File(fileRequest.getFilePath());
    fileRequest.setFileSize(f.length());
    ctx.writeAndFlush(fileRequest);

    new ChunkedFileServerHandler(ctx,f);
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    logger.info("Server read complete");

}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

ChunkedFileServerHandler.java

```
public class ChunkedFileServerHandler extends ChunkedWriteHandler {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

private File file;
public ChunkedFileServerHandler(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, File file) {
    this.file = file;

    logger.info("New ChunkedFileServerHandler");
    ChunkedFile chunkedFile;
    try {
        chunkedFile = new ChunkedFile(this.file);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(chunkedFile);
        ctx.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.channelActive(ctx);
    logger.info("FILE WRITE GETS ACTIVE");
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

**Update**

```
public class ServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

    p.addLast("encoder", new ObjectEncoder());
    p.addLast("decoder",
            new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
    p.addLast("protocolhead", new ProtocolHeadServerHandler());
    p.addLast("filerequestserverhandler", new FileRequestServerHandler());
    p.addLast("chunkedfileserver", new ChunkedFileServerHandler());

}

}
```

Server StartUp

```
public void startUp()
{
        bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
             .childHandler(new ServerInitializer());

            // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
            b.bind(this.port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the pipeline configuration? For instance, do you have a ChunkWriteHandler in your pipeline on server side?

Comment: I made an Update to the question. "ChunkedFileServerHandler" is in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 parts I can see:

1) You shouldn't create a new handler within your own handler, but directly create the ChunkedFile and write it:

```
public class FileRequestServerHandler extends
    SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FileRequestProtocol> {

    private File f;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FileRequestProtocol fileRequest) {
        logger.info("Server new FileRequest " + fileRequest);
        f = new File(fileRequest.getFilePath());
        fileRequest.setFileSize(f.length());
        ctx.writeAndFlush(fileRequest);

        // directly make your chunkedFile there instead of creating a sub handler
        chunkedFile = new ChunkedFile(this.file);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(chunkedFile);// need a specific handler
        // Don't create such an handler: new ChunkedFileServerHandler(ctx,f);
}
```

2) Since you write using ChunkedInput (here ChunkedFile), you must have in your pipeline a ChunkedWriteHandler before your handler, so your Initializer could look like:

```
public class ServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

        p.addLast("encoder", new ObjectEncoder());
        p.addLast("decoder",
            new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
        p.addLast("chunkedWriteHandler", new ChunkedWriteHandler());// added
        p.addLast("protocolhead", new ProtocolHeadServerHandler());
        p.addLast("filerequestserverhandler", new FileRequestServerHandler());
        // removed: p.addLast("chunkedfileserver", new ChunkedFileServerHandler());
    }
}
```

The position of the `ChunkedWriteHandler` could be changed, but always before your own handler where you write the `ChunkedFile`.

3) Final note: have a look and take care of your Encoder/Decoder (ObjectEncoder/ObjectDecoder) since I'm not 100% sure if they can collaborate with such write/read of ByteBuf from/to a file.
It may work, or not...

Comment: Thanks, seems like the Server is sending the File, but client cannot decode it correctly, as you mentioned in 3). I'm getting 'io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 1048576: 4292411364 - discarded'. Do you have some keywords, where to start?

Comment: What I could suggest is to manage both kind of traffics into your own codec. You have to managed both something like header+file transfer, as HTTP does, such that you did not use ObjectDecoder/Coder, but your own codec. See LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder for instance: first byte saying it is an header, then length of the message to generate the FileRequestProtocol object, then following by lengthFile bytes to be catch by your FileChunkReqWriteHandler based on ByteBuf directly (not ChunkedFile) (using the ability of a SimpleChannelInboundHandler to only catch what it should).