# netty tcp bytebuffer server and client

Tags: java, tcp, netty, bytebuffer

After exploring and implementing Proactor design pattern, faced an issue that the client('C' client) connections are no more accepting after a limit. Started to explore netty. Here is what Iam trying to do
1. C client establishes a connection
2. Java Server accepts connection and starts sending 8 Mb size of Byte Buffer to the client using TCP.
Any ideas ? Is netty a good option ? I have browsing for a good examples of netty, unfortunately unlucky.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Ravi

Answer (score 2):

Well yes netty is a good option. You should use [ChunkedFile](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/stream/ChunkedFile.html)

[Here is a good example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357672/sending-file-from-server-to-client-by-using-netty-io)

Comment: Thanks for the response Shubham. I had a look at the example. Why is it hard to find a simple example of transferring a file over TCP from server to client. I saw many comments that netty has good documentation. Surprisingly only discardserver/time server/echo server is the only I have seen so far. Any link to good example will be helpful. Thanks in advance.